# Why can I save without @Transactional?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Simplified example:

```java
@Entity
public class Foo {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;
  private String bar;

  // getters + setters

}

public interface FooRepository extends CrudRepository<Foo, Integer> {
}

@Service
public class FooService {

  private final FooRepository repository;

  public FooService(FooRepository repository) {
    this.repository = repository;
  }

  public Foo save(Foo foo) {
    return repository.save(foo);
  }

}
```

Calling `fooService.save(myNewFoo)` from a controller works, while I would have expected it to fail (if I understand transactions correctly), as no method has been annotated with `@Transactional` (and I actually would like it to fail). Any idea why this behavior? Who's creating a transaction behing the scene, and how to avoid this?

Additional details:

- Java 9
- MySQL connector 6.0.6
- Hibernate 5.2.12
- Spring Boot 2.0.0.M7
- Spring Data JPA 2.0.2.RELEASE

Comment: By default the methods of `CrudRepository` and friends are `@Transactional`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Any way to make them not `@Transactional` then? Apart from rewriting the whole implementation myself? I would like my services to be in charge of transactions, and fail otherwise.

Comment: @M.Deinum Maybe can I extend `SimpleJpaRepository` and disable the `@Transaction`s in some way?

Comment: How about reading the release notes... https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-685

Comment: @M.Deinum Sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The implementation of `CrudRepository#save` provided by Spring creates a transaction by default. Please see [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/jpa/transactions.html) for further details.