# Disabling auto commit in Spring boot not worked

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, hikaricp

I set two parameters to disable auto commit by False but save operation on entity without transaction was committed.

```
spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit=true
```

and the snippet code that I test the behavior is :

```
Log logEntity= new Log();
log.setId("123456789");
logRepository.save(logEntity);
```

after execute this code the `logEntity` saved in table.

How to disable auto commit flag in Spring boot?

Comment: You can use ```@Transactional``` on ```@Service``` level so you will have one transaction per one connection

Comment: I found an older stack question about that. Try this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55343616/how-to-disable-autocommit-spring-boot

Comment: I tried it but didn't work.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the exact same issue. I would like that Spring only commits when I explicitly set a `@Transactional` annotation. Without having to set `@Transactional(MANDATORY)` on every writing Repository method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution, I had to disable it on `EnableJpaRepositories` as following:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"org.company.product"},
                                       enableDefaultTransactions = false)
```

Comment: I can confirm this works!

Answer (score 1):

This didn't let me go. Apparently all methods of `SimpleJpaRepository` are annotated with `@Transactional`, which is the implementation for `CrudRepositories` and `JpaRepository`, and therefore commits after each call.

See: [Why can I save without @Transactional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47813086/why-can-i-save-without-transactional)

Or directly: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#transactions