# Why the data resets after save in database?

Tags: java, mongodb, intellij-idea, spring-data, reset

I'm trying to save new phone number in database

First by another method get phone number and temporary save it and send a code to user then by following methods check if user entered correct code

The controller:

```
    @GetMapping("/check-code/{code}")
    public Boolean checkPhoneNumberCode(@PathVariable("code") int code){
        return phoneService.validateCode(code);
    }
```

The service:

```
    @Override
    public Boolean validateCode(int code) {
        Integer phoneNumberCode = cacheService.getPhoneNumberCode(phoneNumber.toString());
        if (!phoneNumberCode.equals(code)) {
            resendCode();
            return false;
        }
        updateUser();
        clear();
        return true;

    }
```

after the code was ok updateUser() method will call:

```
    @Override
    public void updateUser() {
        User user = userRepository.findByIdAndIsDeletedFalse(userId).get();
        user.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
```

The UserRepository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {
```

And at the end of `updateUser()` method data must be updated and it updated
but when `updateUser()` method finishes
and `validateCode()` method finishes
I've checked, before `checkPhoneNumberCode()` method finishes, data still updated (before "}" finishes and  program exit from debug mode) but when program exit from debug mode (`checkPhoneNumberCode()` method completes) data will reset and back to what was before
I'm using Intellij as IDE and Java for back-end and MongoDB for database I don't think it relates to front-end but I'm using angular for front-end

[Github repository](https://github.com/MatinParsapour/Todo-Web-Back-End)

Controller: src -> main -> ToDoWeb -> controller -> `PhoneController`;
Service: src -> main -> ToDoWeb -> service -> impl -> `PhoneServiceImpl`;
Repository: src -> main -> ToDoWeb -> repository -> `UserRepository`;

Answer (score 0):

It would be difficult to know exactly what the problem is without taking a look at your repository. My guess would be that you're not implementing the repository well, and Spring is not able to create a `Transaction` by default. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47813086/why-can-i-save-without-transactional) deals with something similar.

Check that your `userRepository` either extends from something like `CrudRepository` or `JPARepository`. Another option would be to annotate with `@Transactional` manually on the methods that modify the data in the database.

---

Also, check that your database creation policy is not set to `CREATE`, since this would re-create your data every-time the application is run. You'll probably find this in your `application.properties` file. (I doubt your problem is related to this, but there's no harm in making sure). You can find more information about this in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/what-are-the-possible-values-of-the-hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-configuration-and-wha).

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

I hope this helps, or at least it guides you in the right direction

Comment: Thank you so much for your time I checked my repository again and everything was fine plus this program was working it's not first time yesterday I run my program and checked my program and it was fine and it was working I don't know what's wrong with it that today it's not working

Comment: Without more information it would be very difficult to provide help. Please update your question with more relevant information. A link to an online repository would be even better.